# 2 standard deviation rule

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, fat-tails

I know that 95% of the observations under a normal distribution fall approximately under 2 standard deviations from the mean.  Does this change when the distribution has fat tails?  What is the name of the theorem that guarantees this?

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Associated to this.  Does the distribution even matter?  I think the 2 standard deviation rule applies regardless.  Fat tails just don't matter at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I know that 95% of the observations under a normal distribution fall approximately under 2 standard deviations from the mean.

1.96, but yes.

> Does this change when the distribution has fat tails?

Yes. It also changes with thin tails.

However, there are a lot of distributions with very roughly 95% within two standard deviations. Indeed, if we look at *continuous symmetric unimodal distributions* whose variance exists, there must be between 88% and 100% within two standard deviations.

On the other hand, in the general case, the limit is given by the [Chebyshev inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) - i.e. it may be as low as 3/4.

> What is the name of the theorem that guarantees this?

You don't actually need a theorem; a counterexample to the assertion that it's the case for all distributions would suffice to say that it changes (but since the Chebyshev bound is achievable, it's a good one to look at if you want to mention something). All you really need to do is just compute it for a few different distributions. e.g. look at a uniform and a $t_3$, and some asymmetric and discrete cases.

One interesting case to consider is a distribution that has probability of $\epsilon/2$ at $\pm 1$ and $1-\epsilon$ at 0. Now move $\epsilon$ up and down between 0 and 1 and see the fraction inside two standard deviations can be changed quite a lot.

In that example, the variance is $\epsilon$. If $\epsilon <0.25$ then the proportion inside 2 s.d.s is $1-\epsilon$ (so that proportion can be any value in $(0.75,1)$). Then for $\epsilon > 0.25$ the proportion jumps to exactly 1, which means we can demonstrably achieve any value in $(0.75,1]$, and 0.75 is the Chebyshev bound, so we can't go below 0.75. (It's a very handy distribution to play with.)